# Syntax Error : Unexpected Number / Unexpected Token }

Tags: javascript, php

While working on a dynamic PHP form which allows users to view and edit their data row-wise via an AJAX call, I'm coming across the "unexpected number" error on the Chrome console, and upon making a small change (mentioned ahead), it changes to "unexpected token }". I'm perplexed because I wrote the exact same code for a different form and it worked just fine.

PHP Code snippet -

```
echo "<table id='param-table'><tr ><td >Package Heading</td><td >Package Body</td><td >Special Text</td><td >Edit Package</td><tr>";

    while ($row_users = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        echo "<form onSubmit='return false;' method='POST'><tr ><td >".$row_users['Phead']."</td><td>"."<input name='pbody' type='text'  maxlength='50' value='".$row_users['Pbody']."'>"."</td><td>"."<input name='ptext' type='text'  maxlength='20' value='".$row_users['Ptext']."'>"."</td><td>"."<button onclick='editParam(".$row_users['Phead']." , this)'>Edit Param</button>"."</td></form></tr>"; //".$row_users['Phead'].", this
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

The error arises whenever I click on "edit param", which looks something like this -

```
function editParam(phead, button) {
    var tr, pbody, ptext;

    // Find the row containing these inputs
    tr = button.parentNode;
    while (tr && tr.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== "TR" && tr.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== "BODY") {
        tr = tr.parentNode;
    }
    if (!tr || tr.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== "TR") {
        return; // Something went wrong
    }


    pbody = tr.querySelector("input[name=pbody]").value;
    ptext  = tr.querySelector("input[name=ptext]").value;

    alert(phead+pbody+ptext); // testing
}
```

I've double-checked for any syntax errors, and tried a few dummy tests -

1. Creating a random function to replace the error-causing 'editparam' function, works fine. - meaning problem area lying around the function editparam
2. Using a temporary variable to first store $row_users['phead'] and then pass it to the function, incase there's some issue because of the quotes, but the temp variable still gives "unexpected number".
3. Simply echoing value of $row_users['phead'], which reflects appropriate results. - meaning data being sent isn't a problem either
4. Upon changing `".$row_users['Phead']."` to `'".$row_users['Phead']."'`, the problem becomes "unexpected token }".

Concluding that there is something wrong with the syntax but it's become just so difficult to spot after all these attempts! Any help would be much appreciated for a newbie looking for some light!

Comment: You have a *JavaScript* error. Stop looking at the PHP that generates the JavaScript and look at the actual JavaScript you have.

Comment: You'll also find it a lot easier to debug if you make use of new lines and break out of php mode (`?>`) instead of stuffing everything to an `echo` statement.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a form as a parent to a tr.

Comment: @Quentin, alright, but could you mind telling me what it might be here? I've shared the JS code too.

Comment: You have not shared the output of `echo "<form onSubmit='return false;' method='POST'><tr ><td >".$row_users['Phead']."</td><td>"."<input name='pbody' type='text'  maxlength='50' value='".$row_users['Pbody']."'>"."</td><td>"."<input name='ptext' type='text'  maxlength='20' value='".$row_users['Ptext']."'>"."</td><td>"."<button onclick='editParam(".$row_users['Phead']." , this)'>Edit Param</button>"."</td></form></tr>"; //".$row_users['Phead'].", this`.

Comment: @Quentin, like I mentioned previously, I've used this code before (still running it for the other page) and there's no problem with using form as a parent to tr. And the error remains even if I simply do `alert(phead)` in the js function.

Comment: If you want help with your problem, then provide the people you ask asking to help you with enough code to reproduce it.